# Python: Transform [str] type Json data into [dict] type

Tags: python, json

```
import json

data1 = {'b': 789, 'c': 456, 'a': 123}

encode_line = json.dumps(data1)
decode_json = json.loads(encode_line)

print type(encode_line)
print type(decode_line)
```

The type(decode_line) is [dict], but when we save data1 into an txt file, and read it using below script:

```
file = open('test.txt','r')
for line in file:
    encode_line = json.dumps(line)
    decode_line = json.loads(encode_line)

    print type(encode_line)
    print type(decode_line)
```

Now, the type(decode_line) is [unicode]. why ?

I want to read data from txt file and then retrieve info from dict type. How should I do ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Hi!**

This should do the trick:

```
import json;

def readJSON(filename):
    "Reads JSON file, returns correspoding dict.";
    with open(filename) as f:
        return json.loads(f.read());
```

**How it works:**

`json.dumps(.)` converts Python dict to JSON string.
`json.loads(.)` converts JSON string to Python dict.

In Your code, you call `json.dumps(line)`, but `line` is a string!
For `json.dumps(.)` to work correctly, you must supply a Python dict, not string.

In this context, `dumps` is read as "dump-s", "s" for string. It takes a dict and dumps (i.e. returns) it's string representation. Similarly, `loads` is read as "load-s". It loads (i.e. accepts) a JSON string and returns it's corresponding dict.

**Hope this helps.**

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I want a Python dict from a txt file, but failed. File content is {'b': 789, 'c': 456, 'a': 123}
{'b': 753, 'c': 446, 'a': 223}

Comment: It failed because the text file does not contain valid JSON. JSON uses double quotes for delimiting keys, not single quotes. Also, there should be a single JSON object; in your file, there seem to be two. Are you trying to deal with multiple JSON objects, separated by newlines?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Double quotes is problem. Yes, there is 30000+ lines with JSON form in a txt file and I want to retrieve part info of one line.

Answer (score 0):

remove the following line

> encode_line = json.dumps(line)

from second snippet (where you are reading from file)

```
file = open('test.txt','r')
for line in file:
    decode_line = json.loads(line)
    print type(line)
    print type(decode_line)
```

see https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: We got the  following error :  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/v-fengxw/PycharmProjects/untitled/yyyy.py", line 21, in <module>
    decode_line = json.loads(line)
  File "F:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "F:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "F:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Comment: what is the file content?

Comment: Thanks. The txt file content is {'b': 789, 'c': 456, 'a': 123}
{'b': 753, 'c': 446, 'a': 223}.

Comment: use double quotes {"b": 789, "c": 456, "a": 123} and try

Comment: That's the problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: @noteahp you can accept my answer if it solved the issue